# Create WSDL/SOAP service using CodeIgniter / PHP with a web service method to return the contents of the query as a JSON array

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, soap, wsdl

Like said in my title, i need a SOAP service to return a JSON array which answers a query. Below is my script for the soapServer; this uses the zend framework for creating the server and query assigned to function `getData` function in the class `Test_Server`.

```
class serverTest extends CI_Controller
{
    private $url = http://localhost/myprojects/index.php/test/soapServerTest/;

    function soapServerTest()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('zend');
        $this->load->database('conundrum');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Soap/Server');   
        $server = new Zend_Soap_Server($this->url.'wsdl');
        $server->setClass('Test_Server');
        $server->handle();
    }

    public function wsdl()
    {
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Soap/AutoDiscover');
        $wsdl = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
        $wsdl->setUri($this->url);
        $wsdl->setClass('Test_Server');
        $wsdl->handle();
    }
}

class Test_Server
{
    function getData(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT
        c.client_description AS Client_Desc,
        en1.entity_name AS Parent_Entity_Name,
        en2.entity_name AS Entity_Name,
        tn.trackbacknumber,
        en2.external_reference,
        en2.effective_start_date_time,
        en2.effective_end_date_time
        FROM client c
        INNER JOIN entity_link el
        ON c.pk_client_id=el.fk_client_id
        INNER JOIN entity en1
        ON el.fk_parent_entity_id=en1.pk_entity_id  
        INNER JOIN entity en2
        ON el.fk_child_entity_id=en2.pk_entity_id 
        INNER JOIN trackback_number tn
        ON en2.pk_entity_id=tn.fk_entity_id
        WHERE en1.fk_entity_type_id=2
        AND en2.fk_entity_type_id=1
        GROUP BY en2.pk_entity_id;");

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        return(json_encode($data, TRUE));
    }
}
```

Below is the soapClient script, containing the soapServer url and calling the function containing the query.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/myprojects/index.php/soap1/soapServerTest/wsdl');
echo $client->getData();
```

The query works fine and should return over 1000 rows. The overall aim is to return these results in a json object array. And therefore encode the original xml-based wsdl to a json array.

Thanks for reading this. Hope you can help!

Comment: You can use json_encode.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: i have used json_encode (see code).

Well you can extract my question form my needs which are declared in the title (see title). I need this soap service to return a json array result from the query. The above code is as far as i have got but the wsdl envelope doesn't contain any data rather than expected. I am brand new to codeigniter and zend frameworks. Don't suppose you guys could see where i am going wrong? Many thanks